# Handheld Android 2D Barcode Scanner - How to access the scanner and read data

Tags: android, kotlin, barcode-scanner, pdf417

I'm busy working with an android device that has a physical `barcode` scanner built in. I need to access this scanner and scan a PDF417 `barcode` (like a drivers license).

I found that this to some extent registered as a keyboard, meaning I can get some form of input through the override `onKeyDown` events. Though, when I try and read this data, is comes back as an encoded string or as a replacement character (special character or the diamond with the question mark).

The code looks something like this:

[image]

What I need, is for the result to show me what the value is of the `barcode` I'm scanning.

This is what I'm currently getting:

[image: image2]

Comment: What encoding is the scanner's data in, and what encoding do you want for your output?

Comment: Thats one of the problems - I really don't know what the encoding is. I have very little documentation to work off of. As for output, I just need it in plain readable text.

Comment: Did you check if it matches any of the encodings [listed on the wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PDF417)? Also, it's not entirely clear what _"plain readable text"_ means. I could imagine multiple readable text encodings of a barcode.

Answer (score 0):

Watch carefully setting up your scanner. 
The problem is not in the application. 
In the scanner, you can still add a special of carriage so that the machine will trigger an event onKeyDown